# Generated portlet with xmlportletfactory and Liferay throws BeanLocator is null error

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portal

Im struggling a long time now with the following problem: I generate a very basic (or complex) example portlet with xmlportletfactory. Deploy it to Liferay, add it on a page and try to use it. I can not add a new entry (error message in view) and the server log sais:

```
ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-1][PortletBeanLocatorUtil:42] BeanLocator is null for servlet context coursesExample
```

Environment is:

- liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3
- liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1
- XMLPortletFactory_6.x-v2.2
- Tomcat/7.0.40
- Postgres 9.2
- Java 1.6.0_45

I searched the whole web and find a lot of similiar problems on the liferay forums, but nothing helped me. I posted it also to xmlportletfactory forums http://www.xmlportletfactory.org/forum/-/message_boards/message/145826, but still no answer yet.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried with a Liferay 6.1.1 or 6.1.0? I have a modified version of xmlpf that runs on 6.1.1, and i can share it on github.

Comment: Thank you. The guys from xmlpf are gonna look at this issue the next weeks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for some reason I changed the project's name, and I started having the same "**BeanLocator is null for servlet context**..." problem.
A couple of days later, I renamed my eclipse project to the same name I initially used, and everything went back to normal.

Could that be something related to your project's name as well?